# Gurevich's entropy and topological entropy in a countable Markov shift

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, markov-chains, entropy, thermodynamic-formalism

Good afternoon, I understand that Gurevich's entropy and topological entropy coincide when the countable Markov shift is topologically mixing (right?)

Does anyone know of an example or a reference where Gurevich's entropy and topological entropy in a Markov accounting change do not coincide.

For a definition of Gurevich's entropy see the second section of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.00214.pdf (the original paper is in Russian).

Comment: You would be hard pressed to find a reference. An example would be a case where the Gurevich entropy is periodic. Therefore there would be periods when it would increase slower than topological entropy even if they are equivalent in the long time steps.